# Create JSON object with a new root element in ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I have a JSON object that needs to a new JSON root element. Essentially I need to take the contents of a JSON file and add a new root node on it.

```
{ 
"editable":true,
"gnetId":null,
"graphTooltip":0,
"iteration":1640904925092,
"links":[]
}
```

Needs to become

```
{ 
dashboard: {
"editable":true,
"gnetId":null,
"graphTooltip":0,
"iteration":1640904925092,
"links":[]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the data in the file *data.json*

```yaml
shell> cat data.json 
{ 
"editable":true,
"gnetId":null,
"graphTooltip":0,
"iteration":1640904925092,
"links":[]
}
```

---

Q: ***"Take the contents of a JSON file and add a new root node on it."***

A: [Include the file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html) and declare the root. For example,

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: data.json
        name: dashboard
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  dashboard:
    editable: true
    gnetId: null
    graphTooltip: 0
    iteration: 1640904925092
    links: []
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: data.json
        name: dashboard
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: dashboard
```

---

Q: ***"Handle this for multiple files."***

A: Include the data into variables with a common prefix. Then use lookup plugins *varnames* and *vars* to retrieve the dictionaries into a list. Combine the items. The later items will override the previous ones. For example, given the below files

```yaml
shell> cat data1.yml
key_1a: a
key_1b: b
key_x: 1

shell> cat data2.yml
key_2a: a
key_2b: b
key_x: 2

shell> cat data3.yml
key_3a: a
key_3b: b
key_x: 3
```

The below playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    dashboard: "{{ q('vars', *q('varnames', 'dashboard_.*'))|combine }}"

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
        name: "dashboard_{{ item|basename|splitext|first }}"
      loop:
        - data1.yml
        - data2.yml
        - data3.yml
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: dashboard
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  dashboard:
    key_1a: a
    key_1b: b
    key_2a: a
    key_2b: b
    key_3a: a
    key_3b: b
    key_x: 3
```

Note: This scheme will work when there are no other *dashboard_** variables. If there is a conflict find a unique prefix.

To understand the scheme get the result of the [query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#forcing-lookups-to-return-lists-query-and-wantlist-true)

```yaml
  db_names: "{{ q('varnames', 'dashboard_.*') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  db_names:
  - dashboard_data1
  - dashboard_data2
  - dashboard_data3
```

Display the values of the *dashboard_** variables in a loop

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
      loop: "{{ db_names }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=dashboard_data1) => 
  msg:
    key_1a: a
    key_1b: b
    key_x: 1
ok: [localhost] => (item=dashboard_data2) => 
  msg:
    key_2a: a
    key_2b: b
    key_x: 2
ok: [localhost] => (item=dashboard_data3) => 
  msg:
    key_3a: a
    key_3b: b
    key_x: 3
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. How would you handle this for multiple files? There will be multiple files that will also need to have the dashboard name.

Comment: I added an example.